# Proof of function that gives 1's in binary representation

Tags: binary

There is an older question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911915/number-of-1s-in-the-binary-representation-of-n) that asks about the function $f(n)$ that gives the number of 1's in the binary representation of $n$. Stated in an equivalent way, this function is:

$f(n) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill 1    \hfill & \text{ if $n$ is 1} \\
      \hfill f(z) \hfill & \text{ if $n$ is 2z} \\
      \hfill f(z) + 1 \hfill & \text{ if $n$ is 2z+1} \\
  \end{cases}$

My question is about how it can be proved that $f(n) = b_1(n)$, where $b_1(n)$ is the number of 1's in $n$'s binary representation. At first I thought that it could be proved by showing that there existed $2^x-1 $ numbers whose binary representation is of length $x$ and trying to prove that $f(n_1) + f(n_2) + ... + f(n_{2^x-1})$ (where each $n_i$ is the $i$th number of length $x$) are 1's using the pigeonhole principle, but that seems to go nowhere. How is this function derived, and how can it be proved?

Comment: What does the notation $n_k$ represent?

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. I changed it in the original question. I meant it to mean the $k$th number of length $x$.

Comment: Huh, I would have figured you meant the digit of $n$ at binary index $k$ and then you would use $1,2,...,x$ for indices...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the binary representation of $n$ be denoted $B(n)$.

When $n=1$, it's clearly true.

When $n=2z$, $B(n) = [B(z)\ 0]$, so $B(n)$ has the same number of ones as $B(z)$ does.

Finally, when $n=2z+1$, $B(n) = [B(z)\ 1]$. So $B(n)$ has an additional one compared to $B(z)$.

Comment: You may also want to verify that these three cases cover all natural numbers, and recursively bottom out at n=1.